# value attribute empty although input field is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm inserting an input field into the dom via jquery in a situation that is not reproducable unfortunately.

However, when I write inside the input field its' value won't change.

Have you have seen this behaviour before? And if so how have you dealt with it?

**Just to clarify**

There's no code-example in this question as the error is not reproducable by a simple few lines of code. I would have to include parts of the app which I am not allowed to disclose. Hence I'm asking if people have seen similar behaviour, and where to expect it.

Comment: First we look at the code and then we point out the bug in your code.

Comment: Can you update your question with sample code?

Comment: I have stated in the first sentence that I can't reproduce the situation with a code example. Sorry

Comment: How/when are you checking the value of the input?

Comment: There is nowhere to *expect* this behavior. What you're seeing is a bug that you are introducing with your own code. It is impossible for us to tell what it is without seeing some code, but chances are that either you're fetching the value at a time when it is indeed empty, or your selector matches another element than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that the event handler does not execute for dynamically added elements, this may be a classical mistake like

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    alert('box clicked');
});
var newBox$ = $('<div>').addClass('box').html('Box');
$('#container').append(newBox$); // clicks on this box will not be handled.
```

But if you'll change that JavaScript a little bit, than the events on dynamically added elements will be handled as you want:

**How to change it:**

```
$('#container').on('click', '.box', function() {
    alert('box clicked');
});
var newBox$ = $('<div>').addClass('box').html('Box');
$('#container').append(newBox$); // clicks on this box will be handled.
```

In this way you're binding the event handler to container and an appropriate event handler will be called when the event will bubble up.